# Can we find open sets in Hausdorff spaces as inverses of open sets in $\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: general-topology

I read somewhere that functional analysis can be viewed as a non-commutative analogue to topology by replacing commutative algebras $C(X)$ of continuous functions $X \to \mathbb{C}$ on topological spaces with general non-commutative algebras. This led me to the following question.

Given some topological Hausdorff space $X$, and any open set $U \subset X$, is it always possible to find an open set $O \subset \mathbb{C}$ and a continuous map $f: X \to \mathbb{C}$ such that $U = f^{-1}(O)$?

I know that this fails for general topological spaces $X$, and being Hausdorff seems like the natural condition to demand, but I don't know if it is a necessary condition nor wether it is sufficient. Also, if this holds, by what sets can we replace $\mathbb{C}$?

Edit: I just realised that points which cannot be separated by open sets in $X$ are mapped to the same point by any continuous mapping into a Hausdorff space such as $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: If $X$ is a metric space, that's true. Just take $O = \{z, z \neq 0\}$, and $f(t) = d(t,X \backslash U)$.

Comment: Thanks, @Mindlack! Still looking for the general Hausdorff case though...

Comment: Actually, Wikipedia has the exact notion you're searching for. The class of spaces you're considering are actually the *perfectly normal spaces*, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_space . Indeed, let $F \subset X$ be closed, there is an open $O \subset \mathbb{C}$ and $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that $F = X \backslash f^{-1}(O)$. Let $g(x) = d_{\mathbb{C}}(f(x),\mathbb{C} \backslash O)$, then $g^{-1}(\{0\}) = F$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, Wikipedia has the exact notion you're searching for. The class of spaces you're considering is the class of the *perfectly normal spaces*, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_space . Indeed, let $F \subset X$ be closed, there is an open $O \subset \mathbb{C}$ and $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that $F = X \backslash f^{-1}(O)$. Let $g(x) = d_{\mathbb{C}}(f(x),\mathbb{C} \backslash O)$, then $g^{-1}(\{0\}) = F$.